# How to fix the anaconda environment error?

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to import an environment and getting below error while importing it.

I tried on different machines also, but same error.
Not a network issue, because I tried on AWS and azure cloud machines also.
Not a python version conflict as the machine I tried also doesn't contain any other python versions.

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
- wurlitzer==2.0.1=py38_0
- mkl_random==1.1.1=py38h959d312_0
- wrapt==1.11.2=py38h9ed2024_0
- pyodbc==4.0.30=py38h0a44026_0
- keyring==21.7.0=py38hecd8cb5_0
- libllvm9==9.0.1=h21ff451_1
- sqlite==3.33.0=hffcf06c_0
- argon2-cffi==20.1.0=py38haf1e3a3_1
- gmpy2==2.0.8=py38h6ef4df4_3
- matplotlib-base==3.3.2=py38h181983e_0
- typed-ast==1.4.1=py38h1de35cc_0
- pytest==6.2.1=py38hecd8cb5_0
- distributed==2020.12.0=py38hecd8cb5_0
- lzo==2.10=haf1e3a3_2
- libcurl==7.71.1=h8a08a2b_1
- unixodbc==2.3.9=haf1e3a3_0
- brotli==1.0.9=hb1e8313_2
- py-lief==0.10.1=py38haf313ee_0
- jupyter_core==4.7.0=py38hecd8cb5_0
- mpfr==4.0.2=h9066e36_1
- tornado==6.1=py38h9ed2024_0
- numpy-base==1.19.2=py38hcfb5961_0
- pysocks==1.7.1=py38_1
- sympy==1.7.1=py38hecd8cb5_0
- kiwisolver==1.3.0=py38h23ab428_0
- freetype==2.10.4=ha233b18_0
- cytoolz==0.11.0=py38haf1e3a3_0
- llvmlite==0.34.0=py38h739e7dc_4
- tbb==2020.3=h879752b_0
- pytables==3.6.1=py38h4727e94_0
- qt==5.9.7=h468cd18_1
- zope.interface==5.2.0=py38h9ed2024_0
- libzopfli==1.0.3=hb1e8313_0
- scikit-learn==0.23.2=py38h959d312_0
- mpc==1.1.0=h6ef4df4_1
- rtree==0.9.4=py38_1
- jbig==2.1=h4d881f8_0
- libtiff==4.1.0=hcb84e12_1
- libcxx==10.0.0=1
- matplotlib==3.3.2=hecd8cb5_0
- giflib==5.1.4=h1de35cc_1
- gevent==20.12.1=py38h9ed2024_1
- path==15.0.1=py38hecd8cb5_0
- six==1.15.0=py38hecd8cb5_0
- ruamel_yaml==0.15.87=py38haf1e3a3_1
- libxslt==1.1.34=h83b36ba_0
- imagecodecs==2020.5.30=py38hd12e0e9_2
- watchdog==0.10.4=py38h9ed2024_0
- libarchive==3.4.2=haa3ed63_0
- llvm-openmp==10.0.0=h28b9765_0
- numpy==1.19.2=py38h456fd55_0
- numexpr==2.7.1=py38h16bde0e_0
- zlib==1.2.11=h1de35cc_3
- libxml2==2.9.10=h7cdb67c_3
- ncurses==6.2=h0a44026_1
- certifi==2020.12.5=py38hecd8cb5_0
- scipy==1.5.2=py38h2515648_0
- sqlalchemy==1.3.21=py38h9ed2024_0
- libllvm10==10.0.1=h76017ad_5
- mistune==0.8.4=py38h1de35cc_1001
- spyder==4.2.0=py38hecd8cb5_0
- openssl==1.1.1i=h9ed2024_0
- pywavelets==1.1.1=py38haf1e3a3_2
- conda-package-handling==1.7.2=py38h22f3db7_0
- openjpeg==2.3.0=hb95cd4c_1
- pip==20.3.3=py38hecd8cb5_0
- get_terminal_size==1.0.0=h7520d66_0
- appnope==0.1.2=py38hecd8cb5_1001
- python==3.8.5=h26836e1_1
- mkl==2019.4=233
- pandoc==2.11=h0dc7051_0
- fastcache==1.1.0=py38h1de35cc_0
- libiconv==1.16=h1de35cc_0
- mkl-service==2.3.0=py38h9ed2024_0
- python.app==3=py38h9ed2024_0
- cython==0.29.21=py38h23ab428_0
- pycurl==7.43.0.6=py38hddc9c9b_0
- expat==2.2.10=hb1e8313_2
- psutil==5.7.2=py38haf1e3a3_0
- pillow==8.0.1=py38h5270095_0
- bitarray==1.6.1=py38h9ed2024_0
- glib==2.66.1=h9bbe63b_0
- ipython==7.19.0=py38h01d92e1_0
- appscript==1.1.1=py38haf1e3a3_0
- zeromq==4.3.3=hb1e8313_3
- jpeg==9b=he5867d9_2
- jedi==0.17.2=py38hecd8cb5_1
- zstd==1.4.5=h41d2c2f_0
- libwebp==1.0.1=hd73b212_0
- readline==8.0=h1de35cc_0
- brotlipy==0.7.0=py38h9ed2024_1003
- greenlet==0.4.17=py38haf1e3a3_0
- bzip2==1.0.8=h1de35cc_0
- pyyaml==5.3.1=py38haf1e3a3_1
- gettext==0.19.8.1=hb0f4f8b_2
- lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3=py38h9ed2024_2
- statsmodels==0.12.1=py38h9ed2024_0
- markupsafe==1.1.1=py38h1de35cc_1
- pyrsistent==0.17.3=py38haf1e3a3_0
- libssh2==1.9.0=ha12b0ac_1
- spyder-kernels==1.10.1=py38hecd8cb5_0
- pyqt==5.9.2=py38h655552a_2
- libspatialindex==1.9.3=h0a44026_0
- cffi==1.14.4=py38h2125817_0
- astropy==4.2=py38h9ed2024_0
- msgpack-python==1.0.1=py38hf7b0b51_0
- yaml==0.2.5=haf1e3a3_0
- krb5==1.18.2=h75d18d8_0
- gmp==6.1.2=hb37e062_1
- ca-certificates==2020.12.8=hecd8cb5_0
- bottleneck==1.3.2=py38hf1fa96c_1
- libaec==1.0.4=hb1e8313_1
- dbus==1.13.18=h18a8e69_0
- xlwings==0.21.4=py38hecd8cb5_0
- libffi==3.3=hb1e8313_2
- charls==2.1.0=hb1e8313_2
- regex==2020.11.13=py38h9ed2024_0
- pandocfilters==1.4.3=py38hecd8cb5_1
- notebook==6.1.6=py38hecd8cb5_0
- cryptography==3.3.1=py38hbcfaee0_0
- intel-openmp==2019.4=233
- blosc==1.20.1=hab81aa3_0
- scikit-image==0.17.2=py38h81aa140_0
- pyzmq==20.0.0=py38h23ab428_1
- pkginfo==1.6.1=py38hecd8cb5_0
- pathlib2==2.3.5=py38hecd8cb5_2
- libsodium==1.0.18=h1de35cc_0
- h5py==2.10.0=py38h3134771_0
- libgfortran==3.0.1=h93005f0_2
- pycosat==0.6.3=py38h1de35cc_1
- mkl_fft==1.2.0=py38hc64f4ea_0
- ujson==4.0.1=py38hb1e8313_0
- curl==7.71.1=hb0a8c7a_1
- lz4-c==1.9.2=h79c402e_3
- sip==4.19.8=py38h0a44026_0
- setuptools==51.0.0=py38hecd8cb5_2
- chardet==4.0.0=py38hecd8cb5_1003
- libedit==3.1.20191231=h1de35cc_1
- xz==5.2.5=h1de35cc_0
- jxrlib==1.1=haf1e3a3_2
- pcre==8.44=hb1e8313_0
- icu==58.2=h0a44026_3
- pyerfa==1.7.1.1=py38h9ed2024_1
- snappy==1.1.8=hb1e8313_0
- numba==0.51.2=py38h6440ff4_1
- conda==4.9.2=py38hecd8cb5_0
- libpng==1.6.37=ha441bb4_0
- lxml==4.6.2=py38h26b266a_0
- tk==8.6.10=hb0a8c7a_0
- liblief==0.10.1=h0a44026_0
- pandas==1.1.5=py38hb2f4e1b_0
- lcms2==2.11=h92f6f08_0
- hdf5==1.10.4=hfa1e0ec_0
```

The environment file [link](https://github.com/uday1kiran/pyfinance/blob/main/environment.yml).

Answer (score 0):

This [github issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7311) suggest generating the `.yml` file using the `--no-builds` flag as a possible answer to your problem, but it is possible it might not be enough.